# Custom permalink tag wont work and just gives out 404s

Tags: php, wordpress, function, permalinks

Below I have created a custom permalink tag for my posts, it works as expected and retrieves the parent category and puts it in the URL but for some reason all my posts are giving out 404s and I cant figure out why I have flushed all caches tried saving the permalinks but nothing works.
Not sure if there is problem with the code that's stopping it from working?

```
add_filter('post_link', 'region_cat_permalink', 10, 3);
add_filter('post_type_link', 'region_cat_permalink', 10, 3);
 

function region_cat_permalink($permalink, $post_id, $leavename) {
    if (strpos($permalink, '%region%') === FALSE) return $permalink;
    
$post = get_post($post_id);
if (!$post) return $permalink;
$terms = get_the_category($post->ID);

if (!is_wp_error($terms) && !empty($terms) && is_object($terms[0])) $parentterm = get_cat_name($term[0]->parent);
else $parentterm = 'eu';

return str_replace('%region%', $parentterm, $permalink);
}
```

Comment: Can you give me an example of the link this code generates?

Comment: @Orbital Sure so one of the posts has this URL http://localhost/eu/purus-gravida-quis-blandit-turpis-cursus-61/ which is exactly what I want I just don't understand why its giving out a 404

Answer (score 1):

Go Wordpress Admin => Settings =>  Permalinks

Select Custom Structure and add this

```
/%category%/%postname%/
```

[image]

Then go Wordpress Admin => Settings => Writing

And select eu as default category

Then delete your function

**Update**

```
add_filter('post_link', 'region_cat_permalink', 10, 3);
add_filter('post_type_link', 'region_cat_permalink', 10, 3);
 

function region_cat_permalink($permalink, $post_id, $leavename) {

//print_r($permalink);
$post = get_post($post_id);
if (!$post) return $permalink;
$terms = get_the_category($post->ID);
if($terms[0]->parent > 0) {
$term_name = $terms[0]->slug;
$term_pattern = $term_name . '/';
return str_replace($term_pattern, '', $permalink);
} else {
return $permalink;
}

}
```

Comment: I did try this the problem is there will be multiple parent categories so it won't always be EU that's why I tried to write this function so it can update and be different for each post.

Comment: You dont be allways EU, this option work only if none category selected in post

Comment: Ah right but another Issue we have here is the EU is a parent category so URLs will show as eu/funding/post but I only need the parent category

Comment: You need funding/post or eu/post ?

Comment: I need eu/post and eu is the parent category

Comment: Use updated function

Comment: Thanks that works almost perfectly, the only issue I noticed with this is if a category has multiple parents it will show all of them in the URL like this /asia/esg/postlink but I only want to show the top-level ones

Comment: Also if you have more than two categories selected it puts one of them in there with the parent too, would it be possible to just retrieve the first category get the parent of that and only put that in the URL, I tried to do this but couldn't figure it out.